# Change window position on href

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on a button in my header, it goes to the div id I specified, which is what I want, but my header, which is always on top and fixed at the top of my window, hide the informations. Is there a way to say that when I click my button, the window will go 20px above the div? My code right now:

```
 <nav class="Nav">
        <a class="Navigation" id="FirstHeader" href="#FirstTitle">Title</a>
        <a class="Navigation" id="SecHeader" href="#sSecTitle">Title2</a>
</nav>
```

This put the div I called directly at the top and its hidden by my header. Can I make it so that the div is displayed under my header?

Comment: Please change the question using window _position_. `window.location` is misleading, as it is a part of DOM scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Please use CSS property "position" to address your requirement, as on button click place position in a way making at desired postion with "top", "left", "right", "bottom", please find below code snippet, might be usefull:

```css
#parent { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 400px; 
  background-color: #fafafa; 
  border: solid 3px #9e70ba; 
  font-size: 24px; 
  text-align: center; 
} 
#child { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: #fafafa; 
  border: solid 3px #78e382; 
  font-size: 24px; 
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
 <div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```